# Diablo 2, bug, mercenary losing auras from items

Tags: diablo-ii

I heard that the bug below is still present after many years and patching up to 1.13:

- If your merc dies, he loses all aura's from equipment. You can fix this by reequipping the item, but the merc will only retain the aura from the last item you reequipped.

It this is true, what should I do if my Hireling dies and I have 2 aura items?

- Can this bug be repaired by restarting game?
- Can you re-equip 1 item, take it off, kill your merc, re-equip second item, or something like that?
- Can you do something to items, like selling them and re-buing, to re-enable the auras again?
- Can hiring new merc repair this bug?
- Can you make new runewords and give it to merc instead of old ones, so he will have auras again?
- Or maybe something else is true?

Or you cannot possibly regain your both auras and must to make new character after your mercenary dies?

I cannot check it myself now, as I don't have runes for it, but depending on where the truth lies, I will make or make not the runewords. I don't want to waste runes on runewords that my merc won't be able to use after he dies.

I would be really grateful if someone could help me and explained either how this bug works or how to solve the problem when it occurs.

Comment: Do you play online or local? For local you have the safety of copying your save files to separate place, test it, and see the result. I'm not yet sure, but maybe even online characters are possible to put to offline games the similar way, so you can test it without harm again. I have raised lvl86 assassin offline, and several characters offline, and did not meet with this issue. On the other hand I suggest to get this question to blizzard forums also, they supposedly have more experiece with a specific bug like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a little late, but thank you for your comment, @Sonic. I am playing online now and didn't encountered this bug either. Looks like it was fixed in 1.13d patch:

http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Patch_1.13d_(Diablo_II)